# creating user bot in python, for clicking the messagebutton and joining to channels

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

The issue in the code is that the bot fails to subscribe to the channel specified in the link it sends, and it does not successfully click the button in the received messages. The message sent by the bot is successfully printed to the console, and it contains a link to a particular channel. However, the code is not subscribing to the channel. Additionally, after subscribing, it should click the 'Confirm' button, but it is not doing so. The 'Confirm' button is expected to be located below the messages.

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.custom.messagebutton import MessageButton

api_id = 'api_id'
api_hash = 'api_hash'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

channel_username = 'channel_username'
bot_username = 'bot_username'

async def handle_channel_message(event):
    print("Сообщение из канала:", event.message.text)

    await client.send_message(bot_username, 'кликать')

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[bot_username]))
async def bot_message_handler(event):
    print("Сообщение от бота:", event.message.text)

    if 'https://t.me/' in event.message.text and '♻️ Проверить' in event.message.text:
        channel_link = event.message.text.split('https://t.me/')[1].split()[0]

        await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel_link))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

        buttons = event.message.reply_markup.buttons
        for button_row in buttons:
            for button in button_row:
                if isinstance(button, MessageButton):
                    await button.click()
                    print(f"Успешно подписались на канал и нажали кнопку: {channel_link}")
                    return

        print("Кнопка '♻️ Проверить' не найдена. Проигнорировано.")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[channel_username]))
async def channel_message_handler(event):
    await handle_channel_message(event)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```